# How can I run an ActiveJob in Rails console for debugging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-console, rails-activejob

I currently have an ActiveJob that I've created and use Sidekiq to queue it.  I'm wanting to debug the job, but for me to see any messages I program into it I have to check my log files.  I feel like it would be more convenient to be able to see my `puts` messages in my job in the Rails Console.  When I run the `perform_later` method though in rails console it just queues the job up and I never see the messages in console. Is there a way to make it where I will see them in the console?

Comment: I just open a second console and tails the log... interested to see if there is a better answer!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can run a job with `perform_now`.

For example...

```
class Foo < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(arg1)
    puts "Hello #{arg1}"
  end
end

Foo.perform_now('world')
```

Answer (score 11):

You can temporarily set your queue adapter to inline.

Right now your code in `application.rb` will look something like this:

```
Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

Just comment out the line

```
# Rails.application.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

This will run your job inline, and you should see the results in the console.

Answer (score 9):

You can run with new, Eg.`Foo.new.perform(ar_1, ar_2)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a configuration line you can add in development.rb

```
require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'
```

This should enable inline testing for development.