# How to run a resque job in the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, resque-scheduler, resque-status

I am trying to call a job in the console but always get errors.

Followed the following documentation:

- http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/performance/background_jobs.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrE47tCrZXc
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html
- https://github.com/resque/resque
- [How can I run an ActiveJob in Rails console for debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519414/how-can-i-run-an-activejob-in-rails-console-for-debugging)

Created the following file:
(lib/jobs/archive_survey_jobs.rb)

```
module Jobs
  class ArchiveSurveysJob < ActiveJob::Base
    @queue = :setup

    def perform(survey_type)
      if SurveyTypes.all_classes.map(&:to_s).include?(survey_type)

        surveys = Survey.where(something: 'stuff')\
                        .where.not(something: 'stuff',
                                   something: 'stuff')

        surveys.each do |survey|
          do_something
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I understand that I can do something like `Resque.enqueue(ArchiveSurveysJob, 'string_here')`

How can I call this in the console? If I try:
`Jobs::ArchiveSurveysJob.create(survey_type: 'string_here')`,
when I check the Resque Statuses it resulted in an error: `The task failed because of an error:

> undefined local variable or method `args' for #

If I try this:

```
Jobs::ArchiveSurveysJob.perform(`string_here`)
```

Or:

```
Jobs::ArchiveSurveysJob.perform_now('string_here')
```

I get:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)

Please let me know if I am missing some documentation or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Why did you put the class in a module ? Did you try running `perform_now`with the class outside of the module ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick If I remove it from the module and run: `ArchiveSurveysJob.perform_now(`string_here')` I ged: `uninitialized constant ArchiveSurveysJob`

Comment: `Jobs::ArchiveSurveysJob.perform_now('string_here')` should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I managed to do this was by creating a Rake task and calling the Job there.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `perform` is an instance method. youre calling the class level `perform` which might not have any arguments. I dont know about your version of resque specifically, however you can enqueue jobs from the console like this in at least one version: `Resque.enqueue(Jobs::ArchiveSurveysJob)`

ps, make sure your resque workers are running.
In dev environments I typically have resque running in line:

```rb
# config/initializers/resque.rb
Resque.inline = true if Rails.env.dev? || Rails.env.test?
```

Comment: +1, though, it's better to use `inline` in a block-ensure as [this code (from resque source code)](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/test/job_hooks_test.rb#L464-L473)